# Is it possible to animate constrained height changes of the recycler view when adding/removing items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I would like to achieve the behavior when adding or removing the items to/from the recycler view, it changes its height according to the content up to the specified `@dimen/maxRecyclerViewHeight` value with smooth animation. It's working fine without animation after `notifyItemInserted/Removed` but the views under the recycler view are 'jumping' so that looks a bit odd. Can I achieve that somehow using `TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(...)`? I appreciate any other ideas.

```xml
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/maxRecyclerViewHeight"/>

    <!-- Other views go under the recycler view -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research I found this can definitely be achieved with `TransitionManager`.

Let's assume the xml file containing the constraint layout with the recycler view inside is `activity_example.xml`. So immediately after invoking `notifyItemInserted/notifyItemRemoved` and `notifyItemRangeChanged` you can call something like method below:

```
private void beginDelayedTransition() {
    final ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(this, R.layout.activity_example);

    // this transition is responsible for animation resizing the view
    final Transition transition = new ChangeBounds(); 
    // or any other duration        
    transition.setDuration(250);

    // constraintLayout is a root layout in the activity_example.xml
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout, transition);
    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
}
```

Comment: Great Answer . KUDOS to You. You are the best